# print all inherited values with a super method in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, super

```
package supertest;
public class Parent {
    public void show  (){
        System.out.println(" I am father");     
    }


package supertest;
public class Child  extends Parent{
    public void show(){
        System.out.println("I am child ");
    }
}




public class GrandChild extends Child{

    public void test(){
        super.show();
        System.out.println("I am grand child");

    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        GrandChild gr=new GrandChild();
        gr.test();   

    }
```

The super method prints in output "I am child  I am grand child" 
but I would like to print all three method values "I am father, I am child,  I am grand child" 
How can I fix this

Comment: FYI: I feel you inheritance is incorrect. A grandchild is not always a child or a parent to someone (yet). But a Parent is a child and a grand child to someone. (It is the other way around to make sense). You should be able to tell `Child` is a `Parent` to be correct. But this isn't always correct. `Parent` is a `Child` is.

Answer (score 2):

In `grandChild.show()`, calling `super.show()` will invoke `child.show()`.

So, in `child.show()`, you need call `super.show()` explictly to invoke `parent.show()`:

```
public class Child  extends Parent{
    public void show(){
        super.show();
        System.out.println("I am child ");
    }
}
```